# Yii2 Multi components caching

Tags: caching, yii2

If in Yii2 I using multicomponent  caching and have in my main.php code like this:

```
    'components' => [
        'schemaCache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache'
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache'
        ],
```

Which one of them uses in caching fragment? How can I change it? (for example i what cache schema by MemCache and fragment by FileCache.

```
$this->cacheBegin('some_key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Caching fragments uses `yii\widgets\FragmentCache` Class which uses by default the component with 'cache' id.

So to change this globally you can use the DI container:

Inside your index.php (entry script), after you include the Yii class file

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
```

add the following line (replace 'fragmentCache' with whatever cache component id you want):

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\widgets\FragmentCache', ['cache' => 'fragmentCache']);
```